# Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: literals are not mutable, why?

Tags: ios, swift, function

I want make a function to swap 2 variables! but for new swift, I can't use 'var' ....

```
import UIKit

func swapF(inout a:Int, inout with b:Int ) {
    print(" x = \(a) and y = \(b)")
    (a, b) = (b, a)

    print("New x = \(a) and new y = \(b)")
}

swapF(&5, with: &8)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Literals cannot be passed as inout parameters since they are intrinsically immutable.

Use two variables instead:

```
var i=5
var j=8
swapF(a:&i, with: &j)
```

Furthermore, with one of the last Swift 3 snapshots, inout should be placed near the type, the prototype of your function becomes:

```
func swapF(a:inout Int, with b:inout Int )
```

Comment: thx but ur second approach doesn't work for my Xcode version!

Comment: Do you mean moving the inout? It's not included with XCode yet, you need to wait for preview 3 or 4 i guess. It's available in Swift snapshots built after 20th june.

Comment: No, not even in the last beta of Xcode 8, need to wait for beta3, btw, not a big problem.